# DevXtreme DataGrid in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I need to make a table with `DataGrid` in `Vue`. But I need to display the Data from a `v-for` as you can see in the code i tried i need to display `{{user.name}}`, `{{user.email}}` and `{{rol.name}}`. And I don't know how to do it. Im pretty new to
I tried different thinks but i don't really know how to do it. Thanks all.

Example:

```
<DxDataGrid
    :columns="columns"
    :show-borders="true"
    :focused-row-enabled="true">
  <div v-for="(user,index) in usersData" :key="index">
    <DxColumn caption="Usuario">{{user.name}}</DxColumn>
    <DxColumn caption="Email">{{user.email}}</DxColumn>
    <span v-for="(rol,index) in user.roles" :key="index">
    <DxColumn caption="Roles">{{rol.name}}</DxColumn>
 </span>
</div>
</DxDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you're taking isn't how `DxDataGrid` is typically used.

Instead of using `v-for` within the `DxDataGrid`, you should preprocess your data to fit the structure that `DxDataGrid` expects:

```
computed: {
  processedUsersData() {
    return this.usersData.map(user => {
      return {
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        roles: user.roles.map(rol => rol.name).join(', ')
      };
    });
  }
}
```

And then in template:

```
<DxDataGrid
    :data-source="processedUsersData"
    :show-borders="true"
    :focused-row-enabled="true">
    <DxColumn dataField="name" caption="Usuario"></DxColumn>
    <DxColumn dataField="email" caption="Email"></DxColumn>
    <DxColumn dataField="roles" caption="Roles"></DxColumn>
</DxDataGrid>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! You solved the problem i will read all the devxtreme datagrid docs!